# changing xorg driver for netbook with cedarview integrated graphics

Tags: debian, xorg, drivers, resolution, intel-gma

So I was messing around. I installed debian, everything worked fine. I had to re-install debian for whatever reason. It decided to do something different and now I'm stuck with a 800x600 resolution (display settings don't allow me to go above). I think my problem is similar to this one:

http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/18658/eeepc-intel-cedarview-resolution/

because I'm pretty sure that it's using the VESA driver. Now I'm hoping I can change VESA to the appropriate intel driver. My questions are:

1. how would I change to using the appropriate intel graphics driver (gma3600) ?
2. would changing this driver require reinstalling the operating system? (there was talk of this in the thread I linked to). Or which kernel do I need to have?

Part of the reason why I'm asking is because this seems to require a lot of sensitive configuration and I don't want to spend the next couple of hours (days) troubleshooting.

If it makes any difference the processor is an intel atom N2600.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get grub to setup the VESA mode 1024x600 (or whatever your laptop is supposed to support). For this you need the following lines in `/etc/default/grub`.

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x600x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x600x32
```

You should also use the `fbdev` driver instead of `vesa` for X to get slightly better graphics.

If you are more adventurous, you may want to try the steps I have outlined in my post yesterday:

- http://www.imsc.res.in/~kapil/blog/floss/fixing-a-hole-2013-03-07-00-03